# How to fill the string to another row from the result of ifelse

Tags: r, dataframe

Dataset call : There is a dataframe df, like below :

```
# df
 No. Sub_No. Req_No.
 130   1      231
 130   2      ""
 130   3      ""
 121   1      ""
 140   1      398
 140   2       ""
```

Desired output

```
# df
Type  No. Sub_No. Req_No.
 A    130   1      231
 A    130   2      ""
 A    130   3      ""
      121   1      ""
 A    140   1      398
 A    140   2      ""
```

- You can only define Type : " A " when it has " Req_No "
- Actual dataset mix with another Type and over 1 million rows
- Only approach i have :

  `df["Type"] <- ifelse(grepl("[[:digit:]]",df$Req_No.),"A","-")`

Obviously it can achieve what the desired dataset needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `""` are `NA`, and 'No.' as grouping variable

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(No.) %>% 
  mutate(Type = if(all(is.na(Req_No.))) NA else "A")
```

If it is a blank (`""`) and not NA

```
df %>%
   group_by(No.) %>%
   mutate(Type = if(all(Req_No.=="")) "" else "A")
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups: No. [3]
#    No. Sub_No. Req_No. Type 
#  <int>   <int> <chr>   <chr>
#1   130       1 231     A    
#2   130       2 ""      A    
#3   130       3 ""      A    
#4   121       1 ""      ""   
#5   140       1 398     A    
#6   140       2 ""      A
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(No. = c(130L, 130L, 130L, 121L, 140L, 140L), Sub_No. = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Req_No. = c(231L, NA, NA, NA, 398L, NA)), .Names = c("No.", 
 "Sub_No.", "Req_No."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

#df with blanks
df <- structure(list(No. = c(130L, 130L, 130L, 121L, 140L, 140L), Sub_No. = c(1L, 
 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Req_No. = c("231", "", "", "", "398", ""
 )), .Names = c("No.", "Sub_No.", "Req_No."), row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: or the same with ifelse and adding a select to reorder the columns if needed.. `df2 <- df %>% group_by(No.) %>%
  mutate(Type = ifelse(all(Req_No.==""), "", "A")) %>% 
  select(Type, everything())`